# Where can I read the full Lion EULA?

Tags: macos, virtualization, license

I haven't been able to find this via Google. In particular, I am interested in reading about whether or not a Snow Leopard license is a prerequisite for installing Lion, and the new virtualisation rules.

Does anyone have a link to this?

Comment: I was going to ask -- *why oh why* would you want to read the EULA??!

Comment: EULA stands for "End-User License Agreement". It is the legal document that the user must agree to upon purchasing or installing a software application, and it delineates rights and responsibilities of the software publisher and the purchaser. Now can somebody tell me how I can create a new tag called "EULA"?

Comment: Wheat - I just created the tag (you need higher reputation points). Feel free to edit it with your definition.

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction there's actually little use in reading the thing. EULAs are invalid in Germany, for example, although that doesn't stop US companies to present them as if they aren't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All Apple's hardware & software product agreements can be found at: http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/

Here's straight link to [Lion's agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx107.pdf).

---

Answers to your particular interests can both be found under § 2. B:

> […] you are granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial use, one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly on each Apple-branded computer running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control;
>
> […]
>
> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software.

Comment: Thank very much for your quick response. I wonder why my Googling failed me!

Answer (score 3):

After Lion is in installed, the license (EA0730 revised 2011-06-01) is amongst the documentation:

`/Library/Documentation/License.lpdf`

[image: Finder info for the multilingual PDF]

Comment: What's edited out from my original answer relates to Snow Leopard possibly **not** being a prerequisite in the near future (at the moment, Snow Leopard **is** a prerequisite).

Comment: And the license can also be found through `` → `About this Mac`; where it is the small textual `License agreement` link at the bottom of the dialog.