# Install OS X inside a VMware ESXi server (hypervisor)

Tags: macos, vmware

Say you have a apple hardware, that you installed a VMware ESXi server, is it legal and possible to install a Mac OS X on that hypervisor, and access it remotely, say with RDP or Logmein or whatever to use it as a remote desktop environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple [loosened restrictions around OS X and virtualization with Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20969/292). Previously on OS X Server could be virtualized and even then, only in narrow circumstances. With Lion you could virtualize the non-Server OS X version.

The [Mavericks EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX109.pdf) maintains the Lion virtualization clause. Specifically it says:

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or
>   instances of the Apple  Software within virtual operating system
>   environments on each Mac Computer you own  or control that is already
>   running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software 
>   development; (b) testing during software development; (c) using OS X
>   Server; or (d)  personal, non-commercial use.

So you can:

1. Only virtualize on Apple hardware (which you say you're doing);
2. Only virtualize non-Server for development, testing or "personal, non-commercial use" otherwise you have to use the Server version of OS X ([which is a $20 add-on to Mavericks from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id714547929?mt=12))

Fall within the bounds of the above-mentioned restrictions and yes, you can virtualize OS X in your ESXi environment.

Answer (score 2):

Legally you cannot install OS X on a non-apple branded computer without writen permisson from Apple. You didn't specify which version of OS X you would installing but I'm assuming Mavericks, see the [licensing agreement](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX109.pdf) section 2(A). I'm sure there is similar wording in most of there software licensing agreements.

Comment: He *did* state he's running ESXi on Apple hardware.

Comment: @IanC.You are correct, and 2(B)iii of the license agreement I attached above allows for 2 virtual OS X machines to be ran as long as the host system is a Mac computer and is also running Apple software. I was unclear if he was referring to a Mac host, or some kind of virtual Apple hardware. Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, it's legal to install one OS X virtual machine on Apple hardware. [According to VMware](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/2014/03/os-x-10-9-2-mavericks.html), it's possible to install Mavericks in ESXi 5.5.

(Note that OS X has some secret sauce which prevents it from booting unmodified on VMs which are not hosted on Macs. For example, an OS X VM will shut down if you try to start it on a Windows host.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation set in the esxi local.sh corefile. There is an unlocker available to permit OS X on non-Apple hardware, but it will break the EULA licence terms.