# Is it possible to make a ARM macOS VM on a M1 Mac?

Tags: apple-silicon, virtualization

I have a M1 Mac Mini and a M1 MBP. I'd like to run older versions of macOS that were built for the M1 ARM chip: Big Sur, or later.

However, I have not found good instructions for this - anyone know if it can be done? I use VMware Fusion, but concept is the same for any type-2 hypervisor.

Comment: Please don't include the solution in the question, also don't just post an "it works now" type of answer. If there is an answer you followed, upvote and accept it. If you used a different approach, write your own answer describing the steps you took.

Answer (score 2):

**VMware Fusion**
I gave it a shot with Catalina and Ventura on 2021 M1 MBP (Ventura, Fusion 12.2.4). Same error for both. Did not dig into the logs, went to VMware to check compatibility listings.

[image: Unable to create the installation medium]

From the [July'22 VMware Fusion blog](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2022/07/just-released-vmware-fusion-22h2-tech-preview.html)
*"Fusion will not support running VMs across different architectures. (I.e. no x86_64 VMs on M1 Macs).  macOS virtual machines are out of scope for this release, but it’s something we’re looking into."*

---

**[Parallels](https://www.parallels.com/eu/products/desktop/resources/)**
macOS Monterey 12 (in-app download)
macOS Ventura 13

---

**[UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/)** (based on QEMU) - $10
Runs MacOS 12+, Mac OS 9.2.1, and much more
*"UTM employs Apple's Hypervisor virtualization framework to run ARM64 operating systems on Apple Silicon at near native speeds... [at lower speed] run x86/x64 on Apple Silicon."*

---

**This thread is full of options and ideas**
[Is there a way to run a macOS guest virtual machine on an M1 / Apple Silicon host?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420494/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-macos-guest-virtual-machine-on-an-m1-apple-silicon-hos?rq=1)