# Running Mac OS X on a Windows PC

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows

I have bought a Macbook Pro Retina 13-inch (late 2012 model).

I've been very satisfied with Mac OS X so far and I would like to use it on my home computer, which currently has Windows and Linux on it.

Would it be **legal** (and possible) to make an ISO image of Mac OS X Mavericks from my MBPr and install it on my home PC for everyday usage among my family members? Or do I need to buy the OS as a separate product now?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-os-x-without-purchasing-macintosh-hardware/9877#9877 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19939/where-can-i-read-the-full-lion-eula are good discussions on the EULA. We're not a good place to ask about legality and if you want to do that, you'll have to specify your location since the laws are often very specific and change from location to location. It's possible, so search for hackintosh if you decide to try that out. Also, have a look at our [meta] for the scope of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple’s EULA states that you’re only allowed to install OS X on Apple hardware. If it’s legal to go against an EULA depends on the country and its legislative authority.

Answer (score -1):

The closer you can get to having a PC running OS X is through a virtual machine. Of course, you'll need a machine with a lot of resources (RAM, CPU, ...) to run it smoothly. Of course, this isn't more legal according to Apple's EULA.